# Get the product of review?

Tags: catalog, review

I'm listing [all the reviews](https://www.princessly.com/testimonials/) on a particular page of my magento store:

```
$review_collection = Mage::getModel('review/review')
->getResourceCollection()
->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
->addStatusFilter(Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED)
->setDateOrder()
->addRateVotes();

foreach($review_collection as $_review) {
    // ...
}
```

My question is how can I get the product of each review, something like this:

```
$product = $_review->getProduct();
```

So I can also list the product title and its URL so customers can click on the review to the particular product page.

Better yet, displaying the product cover photo as well so users can compare the product photo with the custom ones.

How can I do this?

Comment: what exact you need?

Answer (score 0):

Got it. Just get product ID of each review and then load its product like this:

```
$productId = $_review -> getEntityPkValue();
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
        ->load($productId);
```